# padding a matrices to equalize heights with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pad

I have a list of matrices, some of them have bigger height (.shape[0]) than the others I want to make them all in equal height. So I want to find the height of the biggest matrix and add pad the rest of matrices with the difference so that the content of amtrix stays in the middle. (if difference is not even then add to the bottom one row more than the top. This i my code so far:

```
def equalize_heights(matrices,maxHeight):
    newMatrices = []
    matricesNum = len(matrices)
    for i in xrange(matricesNum):
        matrixHeight = matrices[i].shape[0]
        if (matrixHeight == maxHeight):
            newMatrices.append(matrices[i])
        else:
            addToTop = (maxHeight-matrixHeight)/2
            addToBottom = (maxHeight-matrixHeight)/2 +((maxHeight-matrixHeight)%2)
```

now matrixes that are not as high as biggest one should have 'addToTop' rows added to the top of martrix (rows filled iwth 0's) and 'addToBottom' rows added to the bottom.

i think im supposed to use numpy.pad function but I don't understand how exactly.

Comment: Why don't you continue by writing the code that calls `numpy.pad` and see how it goes.

Comment: i keep getting columns added isntead of rows

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `np.pad` pads in every dimension, not just the height. Consider using `np.concatenate` instead. Also note that you don't need to pass the maximum height - your function can just calculate that itself.

E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
matrices = [np.array([[1,2], [1,2]]), np.array([[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]])]
def equalize_heights(matrices):
    max_height = matrices[0].shape[0]

    for matrix in matrices[1:]:
        max_height = max(max_height, matrix.shape[0])

    for idx, matrix in enumerate(matrices):
        matrices[idx] = np.concatenate((
            matrix,
            np.zeros((max_height - matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1]))
            ))
```

Note that this will not center your matrices the way you wanted, but that shouldn't be too difficult. (Put three arrays in the tuple to concatenate, rather than two.